# Binomial random variable multiplied by a positive constant

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have $$X \sim Bin(n, p)$$
Let $Y \equiv \frac{X}{n}$ such that $n>0$
What's the distribution of $Y$?
Using expectation and variance properties we got that:
$EY = p$
$VY = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$
Is also $Y$ binomial?

Comment: If $n\neq1$ then the distribution of $Y$ is not binomial. I am not familiar with a specific name for it.

Comment: Binomial variables $X$ only take integer values, while $X/n$ can be noninteger. There is no reason to give $X/n$ a name since it is best described as a multiple of a Binomial variable. [@Vera : I accidentally double-clicked to "+1" your comment, which leaves it unchanged, but when I try to +1 it, it says that I have clicked too many times for new changes to occur.]